# How do I group and number neighboring pixels in the picture?

Tags: python, image, image-processing, multidimensional-array, opencv

I have a 4-channel PNG image with instance segmentation. In this picture, the value of pixels containing objects is [class_number, 0,0,100] and the value of pixels without objects is [0,0,0,0] (Class_number: 1 - 8). Sample picture is below[image]

The gray areas in the picture are all independent objects. I want to number these objects starting from 1 and write this number in the 3rd channel of the pixel (For example, all neighboring pixels for the first object will be [class_number, 0,1,100] and so on for all objects in this picture)

Could you please give a hint, how can I do this in python?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected-component_labeling

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this technique does not give the result I want. My picture has 4 bands and I cannot do any morphological operation on it (since the information contained in the pixels will be lost). I have to do this process with loops. Do you have any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can use only first channel as one dimensional image and apply connected component labelling, as suggested by @Piglet.

Step 1: Convert all the different classes in the first channel as white regions in black and white image. and no class as black regions.

Step 2: apply connected component labeling to the black and white image obtained in step 1

Step 3: update original image 3rd channel with the connected component labeled image.

Hope this helps.

Cheers!